# My device has files listed as other in one of my old file explorers but I could not access them they are eating my internal memory

Tags: lenovo

Does anyone know how to get rid of these files they will not show up at all not even to anti-virus software but they are using all internal memory I clear up within minutes

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102966/discussion-on-question-by-nathaniel-my-device-has-files-listed-as-other-in-one-o).